# asp.net-mvc How To Add Object While Iterating (Foreach)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a view like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart()
        .Name("chart-store")
        .Title("Percentage Store Rent")
        .Legend(legend => legend
            .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)
        )
        //.SeriesColors(new string[] { "#42a7ff", "#666666", "#999999", "#cccccc", "#013A5E" })
        .Series(series => {
            series.Pie(new dynamic[] {
                new {category = "Living Room",value = 35},
                new {category = "Dinning Room",value = 25},
                new {category = "Study Room",value = 20},
                new {category = "Bedroom",value = 10},
                new {category = "Outdoor",value = 10}                
            })
            .Labels(labels => labels
                .Visible(true)
                .Position(ChartPieLabelsPosition.OutsideEnd)
                .Template("#= category # - #= kendo.format('{0:P}', percentage)#")
                .Background("transparent")
            );
        })
        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
            .Visible(true)
            .Template("#= category # - #= kendo.format('{0:P}', percentage) #")
        )
    )
```

the series.Pie data is still static. i want that data get from database.. and i have done with my code below. but only give one row data..

**VIEW**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart()
        .Name("chart-store")
        .Title("Percentage Store Rent")
        .Legend(legend => legend
            .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)
        )
        //.SeriesColors(new string[] { "#42a7ff", "#666666", "#999999", "#cccccc", "#013A5E" })
        .Series(series => {
            series.Pie(new dynamic[]{@g**.app.web.Controllers.Tran******Controller.GetPieChartByRoom()})
            .Labels(labels => labels
                .Visible(true)
                .Position(ChartPieLabelsPosition.OutsideEnd)
                .Template("#= category # - #= kendo.format('{0:P}', percentage)#")
                .Background("transparent")
            );
        })
        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
            .Visible(true)
            .Template("#= category # - #= kendo.format('{0:P}', percentage) #")
        )
    )
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public static object GetPieChartByRoom() {
            List<string> mHBM = new List<string>();
            mHBM.Add(mcHBM_SALES);
            mHBM.Add(mcHBM_BusinessPartner);
            mHBM.Add(mcHBM_Employee);
            mHBM.Add(mcHBM_LIST);
            mHBM.Add(mcHBM_GeneralListType);
            ISession voISession = NHibernateSession.OpenSession(mHBM);

            var getRoom = voISession.QueryOver<Lists>().Where(w=>w.Type==17).List();
            var voTable = new object();
            foreach (var ListRoom in getRoom)
            {
                var RoomCount = voISession.QueryOver<SalesAgreementDetail>().Where(w => w.Room == ListRoom.ListID).RowCount();
                voTable = new { category = ListRoom.ListName, value = RoomCount };
            }

            return voTable;        
        }
```

thank you for your attention, and sorry for my bad english :D

Comment: post the complete code the name of the list i think you should use like foreach(var room in ListRoom)

Comment: thanks for your response, i have done updating post.. can you help correct it. where my fault?

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
var voTable = new object();
foreach (var ListRoom in getRoom)
{
  var RoomCount = voISession.QueryOver<SalesAgreementDetail>().Where(w => w.Room == ListRoom.ListID).RowCount();
  voTable = new { category = ListRoom.ListName, value = RoomCount };
}

return voTable;
```

You are assigning a new object to `voTable` in the loop rather than adding the new objects into it, This is the reason you are getting only one row in the graph as you are passing only one row at the end.

What you need is to **Add the new objects into the `voTable` variable**. Like below

```
var voTable = new List<object>();   //changes here
foreach (var ListRoom in getRoom)
{
  var RoomCount = voISession.QueryOver<SalesAgreementDetail>().Where(w => w.Room == ListRoom.ListID).RowCount();
  voTable.Add(new { category = ListRoom.ListName, value = RoomCount }); //changes here
}

return voTable;
```